# Vue warns me Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: null

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

While fetching data from `Firebase` I am trying to set the `properties` of the `object` obtained to the UI, but when I try and set any changes to the data, it throws me this error.
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'cc' in null.

I am using Vue in development mode, along with `Firebase`.Is there any concept I am missing out on?

```
beforeCreate(){
sref.get().then(sc => {
      if (sc.exists) {
        console.log(sc.data()); //this logs in the correct data
        this.school = sc.data(); //this too
        this.cc = sc.data().cc;  //also this
        this.name = sc.data().name;
```

When I do

```
console.log(this.name)
```

In `created()` it displays undefined, any attempt to change or update also gives an error

```
Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: null
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'cc' in null"

found in

---> <VSelect>
       <VForm>
         <VCard>

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'cc' in null
    at Proxy.set
```

Answer (score 10):

I figured out where I went wrong there, in my template `v-model` i was using `this.school`, `this.name`, `this.cc` which was causing the warnings to come, but I am still not clear at the internals of the working. I would like if someone pointed me to the right resources.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error attempting to set data in the v-model. My setup was as follows:

```
<template>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="this.myVariable"
        :readonly="false"
        :disabled="false"
        persistent-hint
        outlined
      ></v-text-field>
</template>

data() {
    return {
      myVariable: "1",
    }
}
```

This was not updating `myVariable` because of the `this` keyword on the line setting the v-model. Changing to the following resolved the errors for me:

```
<template>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="myVariable"
        :readonly="false"
        :disabled="false"
        persistent-hint
        outlined
      ></v-text-field>
</template>

data() {
    return {
      myVariable: "1",
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution also worked for my `:some-value.sync` situation.

Answer (score 1):

One other more exotic case is, when your data function is placed inside of a mixin that is shared between multiple scripts where one of the scripts has no data property i.e. `shool` defined - then you'll recieve the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: add v-if check for your dataset, where you use v-for. Maybe you will need `template` to do this.

Comment: The issue is I am able to retrieve the data and show it in my textfields but when I try and make any change on it. The above warning pops up for every keystroke, same for selects. I cannot ignore the warning cause its not updating my data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but in a different place, where I tried `this.userDialogVisible` (error) instead of `userDialogVisible` (correct):

```
<el-dialog
  title="Create a user"
  :visible.sync="userDialogVisible"
  :show-close="false"
  width="50%">
  <!--      dialog content-->
  <span>This is a message</span>
  <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
    <el-button type="primary" @click="userDialogVisible=false">Confirm</el-button>
    <el-button @click="userDialogVisible=false">Cancel</el-button>
  </span>
</el-dialog>
```

The error is "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'userDialogVisible' in null".

This is because `this.userDialogVisible` is referencing a global property at the `beforeCreate` stage, where it is null. but it is then populated by the value you assign to it at the `created` stage.

Thus, if `this.xxx`, `this.$xxx` or `this.Ωxxx` is being accessed at the `beforeCreate` stage, Vue.js will only try to reference a global property named `xxx`.

In your case, any data fetching from a backend server (firebase etc.) should be done in a place like `created`, or `mounted`, not in `beforeCreate`, unless you explicitly want to deal with global properties.

I do not think that you can reference any local properties defined in `data()` by using `this.xxx` at the `beforeCreate` stage.

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)